# How do you compile a glfw/opengl/imgui project with mingw on Linux to make a windows executable?

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, cross-compiling, glfw

I am making a simple C++ app using imgui* + glfw + opengl, I am compiling with g++ and developing on arch Linux (btw)

*imgui is a "library" for making GUIs that you simply copy all of it's source files in your project to use it

The app compiles and works when compiled with g++. But I want the app to also work for windows. So I'm trying to compile it with mingw.

I have installed mingw-w64 and downloaded the glfw binaries for mingw from the glfw website (glfw-3.3.9.bin.WIN64)

I have a bunch of glfw files which I'm not sure exactly what to do with them such as "glfw3.h", "glfw3.dll", "libglfw3.a", "libglfw3.dll.a", "glfw3.lib", etc...

When I try to run the same command as the Linux compilation but with mingw instead of g++, I get this error:

```
sources/main.cpp:6:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
libraries/imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:79:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
   79 | #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:33: windows] Error 1
```

When I try:

- adding flags like "-lglfw3" or modify my makefile in other ways (as per chatgpt's and Google's suggestions)

Examples of stuff I tried doing (edited from stuff chatgpt gave me)

```
CXXFLAGS_linux = -std=c++17 -Wall -lOpenGL -lglfw -I$(GLFW_DIR) -I$(IMGUI_DIR) -I$(NLOHMANN_DIR)
LDFLAGS_linux = -L$(GLFW_DIR) -L$(IMGUI_DIR) -lGL -lglfw

CXXFLAGS_windows = -std=c++17 -Wall -I$(GLFW_DIR) -I$(GLFW_DIR)/GLFW -I$(IMGUI_DIR) -I$(NLOHMANN_DIR)
LDFLAGS_windows = -L$(GLFW_DIR) -L$(IMGUI_DIR) -lglfw3 -lopengl32
```

```
ifeq ($(filter windows%,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
    # On Linux, link against dynamic libraries
    CXXFLAGS += -lGL -lglfw
    LDFLAGS += -lGL -lglfw
else
    # On Windows with MinGW, link against static libraries
    CXXFLAGS += -lopengl32 -lglfw3 -mwindows
    LDFLAGS += -lopengl32 -lglfw3
endif
```

EDIT: After making a few modifications based on comments, I don't have this error anymore, instead of getting an error on the include. I get an error telling me that every glfw function is undefined :

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `glfwSetErrorCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x103): undefined reference to `glfwSwapInterval'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2d5): undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xbce): undefined reference to `glfwGetFramebufferSize'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xbeb): undefined reference to `__imp_glViewport'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xc49): undefined reference to `__imp_glClearColor'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xc57): undefined reference to `__imp_glClear'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xc75): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xc84): undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `glfwGetClipboardString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `glfwSetClipboardString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x4b7): undefined reference to `glfwGetKey'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x4cd): undefined reference to `glfwGetKey'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x506): undefined reference to `glfwGetKey'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x51c): undefined reference to `glfwGetKey'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x555): undefined reference to `glfwGetKey'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x56b): more undefined references to `glfwGetKey' follow
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x7b9): undefined reference to `glfwSetErrorCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x7ca): undefined reference to `glfwGetKeyName'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x7da): undefined reference to `glfwSetErrorCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x7e4): undefined reference to `glfwGetError'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0xe85): undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowFocusCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0xea0): undefined reference to `glfwSetCursorEnterCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0xebe): undefined reference to `glfwSetCursorPosCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0xedc): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0xefa): undefined reference to `glfwSetScrollCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0xf18): undefined reference to `glfwSetKeyCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0xf36): undefined reference to `glfwSetCharCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0xf50): undefined reference to `glfwSetMonitorCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0xff6): undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowFocusCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x100d): undefined reference to `glfwSetCursorEnterCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1024): undefined reference to `glfwSetCursorPosCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x103b): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1052): undefined reference to `glfwSetScrollCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1069): undefined reference to `glfwSetKeyCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1080): undefined reference to `glfwSetCharCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1093): undefined reference to `glfwSetMonitorCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1257): undefined reference to `glfwSetErrorCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1265): undefined reference to `glfwCreateStandardCursor'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1277): undefined reference to `glfwCreateStandardCursor'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1289): undefined reference to `glfwCreateStandardCursor'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x129b): undefined reference to `glfwCreateStandardCursor'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x12ad): undefined reference to `glfwCreateStandardCursor'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x12bf): more undefined references to `glfwCreateStandardCursor' follow
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1309): undefined reference to `glfwSetErrorCallback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1313): undefined reference to `glfwGetError'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x133d): undefined reference to `glfwGetWin32Window'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x14e1): undefined reference to `glfwDestroyCursor'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x15a4): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowAttrib'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x15fd): undefined reference to `glfwSetCursorPos'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1621): undefined reference to `glfwGetCursorPos'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x16bf): undefined reference to `glfwGetInputMode'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1716): undefined reference to `glfwSetInputMode'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1757): undefined reference to `glfwSetCursor'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x176e): undefined reference to `glfwSetInputMode'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x17f9): undefined reference to `glfwGetGamepadState'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1e3f): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowSize'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1e59): undefined reference to `glfwGetFramebufferSize'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTR7HiF.o:imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1ef2): undefined reference to `glfwGetTime'
```

- Putting the weird glfw files in my project (in a folder named libraries/glfw as shown in my file structure below)
- I'm getting really tired, I have been changing things around back and forth hoping for it to work or for something to change

I always get the same problem, often it even creates this error for the Linux compilation

Depending on the exact configuration, sometimes the windows compilation fails instantly and sometimes it takes a while before giving the error

On a specific configuration that I don't manage to recreate, I noticed that replacing the #include <GLFW/glfw3.h> with <glfw3.h> in both my files and the imgui files made the error go away. BUT it would then create other errors about every glfw function not being defined, and I don't think I should be modifying the imgui files anyways

My makefile last time I touched it (in this version, Linux compiles and Windows gives the error stated above)

```
SOURCE_DIR = sources/

LIBRARIES_DIR = libraries/

IMGUI_DIR = $(LIBRARIES_DIR)imgui/
NLOHMANN_DIR = $(LIBRARIES_DIR)nlohmann/
GLFW_DIR = $(LIBRARIES_DIR)glfw/

# List all your source files
FILES = $(SOURCE_FILES) $(IMGUI_FILES) $(NLOHMANN_FILES)
SOURCE_FILES = $(SOURCE_DIR)main.cpp $(SOURCE_DIR)database/database.cpp $(SOURCE_DIR)database/element.cpp $(SOURCE_DIR)style/colors.cpp $(SOURCE_DIR)ui/display.cpp
IMGUI_FILES = $(IMGUI_DIR)imgui.cpp $(IMGUI_DIR)imgui_demo.cpp $(IMGUI_DIR)imgui_widgets.cpp $(IMGUI_DIR)imgui_tables.cpp $(IMGUI_DIR)imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp $(IMGUI_DIR)imgui_impl_glfw.cpp $(IMGUI_DIR)imgui_draw.cpp $(IMGUI_DIR)imgui_stdlib.cpp
NLOHMANN_FILES = $(NLOHMANN_DIR)json.hpp

####################################################################################################

GPP = g++
MINGW = x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++

CXXFLAGS_linux = -std=c++17 -Wall -l OpenGL -l glfw -I $(GLFW_DIR) -I $(IMGUI_DIR) -I $(NLOHMANN_DIR) 
LDFLAGS_linux = -L$(GLFW_DIR) -L$(IMGUI_DIR)

CXXFLAGS_windows = -std=c++17 -Wall -lopengl32 -lglfw3 -L $(GLFW_DIR)/GLFW -I $(GLFW_DIR) -I $(IMGUI_DIR) -I $(NLOHMANN_DIR)
// I added the -L to help mingw find the glfw files that are in two consecutive glfw/ folders
LDFLAGS_windows = -L$(LIBRARIES_DIR) -L$(IMGUI_DIR)

####################################################################################################

all: linux windows

linux: $(FILES)
    $(GPP) $(CXXFLAGS_linux) $(LDFLAGS_linux) $^ -o LOAD_$@
windows: $(FILES)
    $(MINGW) $(CXXFLAGS_windows) $(LDFLAGS_windows) $^ -o LOAD_$@

clean:
    rm -f LOAD_linux
    rm -f LOAD_windows
```

My file structure :

```
database/
     // Data my app uses while running
libraries/
     glfw/
          GLFW/
               glfw3.h
               glfw3native.h
               libglfw3.a
               libglfw3dll.a
               // At first, I thought I should put my files directly in libraries/glfw, but as a comment said, it should be in libraries/glfw/GLFW/ instead
     imgui/
          imgui.h
          imgui.cpp
          imgui_demo.cpp
          imdui_draw.cpp
          // etc...
     nlohmann/
          json.hpp
sources/
      main.cpp
      database/
      style/
      ui/
      
Makefile
LOAD_linux (when it compiles)
LOAD_windows.exe (when it compiles)
```

My includes above my main.cpp (the rest of the code shouldn't be important as it works fine when compiling for Linux)

```
#include "imgui.h"
#include "imgui_impl_glfw.h"
#include "imgui_impl_opengl3.h"
#include "imgui_stdlib.h"

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> 

#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include "database/database.h"
#include "database/element.h"

#include "ui/display.h"

#include "style/colors.h"
```

As I've seen some people suggest on other topics, I might use a virtual machine instead of a cross compiler. But I will eventually need cross compiling for some projects.

Comment: If the headers are not found, you need to specify a path to the directory they're in with `-I`. *"I have a bunch of glfw files"* Your linker wants `libglfw3.dll.a` (or `libglfw3.a` for static linking), and will look for it if you pass `-lglfw3`. If it can't find it, specify its directory with `-L`.

Comment: Please edit your "file structure" block with an *exact* file tree. It is kind of important for us to know whether you have a `libraries/glfw/GLFW3` directory with a `glfw3.h` file inside it, for example.

Comment: I made some modifications to my initial post after applying your advice. I don't know if that is how I should do it. I have put my glfw3 files (glfw3.h, glfw3native.h, libglfw3.a, and libglfw3dll.a), all in libraries/glfw/GLFW instead of libraries/glfw where they were before. And I have added the -L libraries/glfw/GLFW to my makefile. Now I don't have the include error, but I have an error telling me that glfw functions don't exist : /tmp/ccfaUFRz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `glfwSetErrorCallback' (same for every glfw function)

Comment: Usually you'd store .h and .a separately, but it's just a convention. Can you show the full linking command?

Comment: You mean this ? MINGW = x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ (new line) CXXFLAGS_windows = -std=c++17 -Wall -lopengl32 -lglfw3 -L $(GLFW_DIR)/GLFW -I $(GLFW_DIR) -I $(IMGUI_DIR) -I $(NLOHMANN_DIR)
(new line ) LDFLAGS_windows = -L$(LIBRARIES_DIR) -L$(IMGUI_DIR) (new line) $(MINGW) $(CXXFLAGS_windows) $(LDFLAGS_windows) $^ -o LOAD_$@

Comment: Please add `@username` when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications. No, I mean the command that Make prints when running it, with all variables expanded.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You mean this one ? x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -L libraries/glfw/ -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32  -I libraries/glfw/ -I libraries/imgui/ -I libraries/nlohmann/ -Llibraries/ -Llibraries/imgui/ sources/main.cpp sources/database/database.cpp sources/database/element.cpp sources/style/colors.cpp sources/ui/display.cpp libraries/imgui/imgui_tables.cpp libraries/imgui/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp libraries/imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp libraries/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp libraries/imgui/imgui_stdlib.cpp libraries/nlohmann/json.hpp -o LOAD_windows ./libraries/glfw//glfw3.dll

Comment: Note that I removed a few imgui files that seemed unimportant from the above message because the message was too long

Comment: `-l` have to be after `.cpp` (or `.o`). You also don't need `.dll`s in there, `-l` is enough.

Comment: Also, manually specifying flags for use a library is stone age technology. :P You should be using `pkgconf`. For cross builds, you'll need to point it to the libraries you've downloaded, but it's still better than manually specifying the flags. Also my https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2 could be of use, it automates installing libs for MinGW and has pkgconf working out of the box.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I know that this is very late, but I just wanted to come back and say that your solution about putting -l after the .cpp worked